# React Native + React Query useQuery staleTime not work

Tags: react-native, react-query

I've this simple screen in react native

```
const getReservations = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('https://artisanlab.it/test.php');
  return response.json();
};

const Dashboard = ({navigation}) => {

  const {data} = useQuery('getReservations', getReservations, {
    staleTime: 1000,
  });

  if (!data) {
    return <Text>Loading...</Text>;
  }

  return (
    <Box flex="1" safeAreaTop bg="light.100">
      <Text>data: {data.title}</Text>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

Why **staleTime** do not invoke every second the endpoint settend into **getReservation** function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why staleTime do not invoke every second the endpoint settend into getReservation function?

because that's not what staleTime does. staleTime just marks the query data as being stale, meaning its now outdated, so the next time on a mount / windowFocus / networkReconnect, it will be refetched. react-query does *not* refetch a stale query on every render.

If you want an interval fetch, you're looking for `refetchInterval: 1000`.